# Check if Netflix Account is valid

Tags: php, rest, netflix

Is there a way to check if the account is valid in Netflix and return a JSON response? For a URL example:

> https://developers.netflix.com/api/account?u=username&p=password&token=token

Comment: Are you asking how to make that HTTP request and parse the JSON in PHP?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there is a Netflix API that could check if the account is still valid. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Netlifx killed its public API in 2014. As far as I know they allow no way to authenticate a user... I may be wrong but I can't see anything they've replaced their old API with.

Comment: You could look for a solution like this, it will only prove if the user is logged in though: https://robinlinus.github.io/socialmedia-leak/